# Get components of a form at design time

Tags: forms, delphi, components, design-time

I created a component which when one double-clicked it at design time, it creates another form. The code for that is the following:

```
function TMyComponentTest1.Execute: Boolean;
var
  Form: TMyComponentTest1Form;
begin
  try
    Form := TMyComponentTest1Form.Create (nil);
    Form.ShowModal;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In this new form I have to get the components of the main design form, but I couldn't do that, does anyone has an idea of how I can accomplish that?
I also try to create with "self" but then when I double-clicked it, delphi crashes...

Comment: `Create` should be immediately *before* you enter `try`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some untested code that I think will work. Let us call your component TMyComponent. You must surely be creating your TMyComponentTest1Form in the designtime package of TMyComponent as part of a component editor and/or a property editor.

Then, try creating the TMyComponentTest1Form like this:

```
function TMyComponentTest1.Execute: Boolean;
var
  aForm: TMyComponentTest1Form;
  OwnerForm: TForm;
  aMyComponent: TMyComponent;
begin
  {OwnerForm is your main design form}
  OwnerForm := nil;

  {Get your component on the main design form}
  aMyComponent := TMyComponent(GetComponent(0))

  {Make sure your component's owner is a TForm}
  if (aMyComponent.Owner is TForm) then
    OwnerForm := TForm(aMyComponent.Owner);

  {You problem may be solved by making component form owner the Application}
  aForm := TMyComponentTest1Form.Create(Application);
  try
    {
    Now you should be able iterate the components owned by OwnerForm
    right here. If you do not want to do it here, add a TForm property 
    to your component and assign OwnerForm to it.
    }
    aForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    aForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```